# What is the nature of a wave of a particle (neutron/proton/electron) depend upon? Like is the amplitude or wavelength always constant?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, wavefunction

Or are there factors on which amplitude and wavelength and energy of a wave of a particle depend upon?

Comment: Many things. particle energy depends on it's speed (if it has non-zero rest mass), on whether it is in a quantum well and on which level respect from the ground it resides, whether particle experiences Doppler shift, non-linear medium effects, and many more, too broad question in principle.

Answer (score 1):

Amplitude and wavelength of a particle are generally not constant.

The wavelength ($\lambda$) depends on the mass ($m$) and velocity ($v$) of the particle by
$$\lambda=\frac{h}{mv}$$
where $h$ is Planck's constant.
This was first [hypothesized by de Broglie](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matter_wave#De_Broglie_hypothesis) (in 1924),
and a few years later [experimentally confirmed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matter_wave#Experimental_confirmation).

The amplitude usually varies from place to place.
It is big where the particle is likely to be,
and it is small where the particle is unlikely to be.
This is known as [Born's rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Born_rule).